# How is the internal buffer of a readable node stream working?

Tags: node.js, stream, buffer

Is there any explanation of the following behavior that seems to contrast with the official [Node streams documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/stream.html)?

In Node REPL (v16.17.0):

```js
> s=stream.Readable.from('a')
> s._readableState.buffer
BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 }
```

Why is the buffer empty (length 0) here?

Nevertheless, I can read with `.read()`:

```js
> s.read()
'a'
```

This behavior seems to conflict with [Documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/stream.html#readablereadsize):

> The `readable.read()` method reads data out of the internal buffer and returns it.

Is this description correct? If yes, where can I see that "internal buffer"? Is it different from the value of `._readableState.buffer`?